Issue with AWS Application Load Balancer
I have an ecs fargate cluster with about five tasks. However, I noticed that these instances dont scale pass 10 users during a load test. Upon further debugging, I had to ssh into each of these instances and did a htop to see the cpu and memory utilization of these five tasks. I noticed that one of these tasks had 100% cpu utilization and the rest had no cpu utilization. This makes the cpu utilization get very high and makes the ecs tasks unhealthy and unable to receive more traffic.
This image shows the ecs cpu utilization for one instance. How can i ensure this traffic is evenly distributing the traffic to all tasks in the ecs service.
Upon checking my load balancer access logs, I also noticed that a lot of requests came from one ip address.
I tried modifying the load balancer traffic distribution style to round robin but it still doesnt distribute traffic evenly across all my tasks. What can I do to ensure scalability of my application?


Do you have sticky sessions enabled in the target group? Are you actually sending traffic to the load balancer's DNS address?

No sticky sessions are not enabled . The flow is from route 53 --> Load balancer --> Target group --> ECS tasks. Also, cross zone load balancing is enabled and all my target groups are in the same AZ as my load balancer.
